# how can i programatically to turn wifi on/off in windows10

Tags: switch-statement, wifi

Not using netsh, I found a way to switch airplane mode([Programmatically turn airplane mode on or off Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814580/programmatically-turn-airplane-mode-on-or-off-windows)), but I can't find any way to switch wifi state by code. Does any one know?

Comment: You should use WlanSetInterface function with wlan_intf_opcode_radio_state flag.

Comment: @Mike Petrichenko thx man